# How to filter the response from woocommerce rest API?

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I need to filter the response of woocommmerce Rest API. It gives more than enough unnecessary response while making http requests. For example. When i need to show the products of specific category. I just need product id, image and slug but m getting unnnecesary fields too of 250 lines of heavy response for single product. So , I wanna get only specific fields. There is plugin for wordpress rest api filter but it doesn't work for woocommerce. Any way to solve my problem?

Comment: Where is your code?

Answer (score 0):

When you build your model , do not create all fields in Java/Kotlin , just add the fields you need and assign those values by the converter , it could be a Gson , or Moshi whatever .

Comment: please read the question carefully . I am talking about the unncessary response. I know i can take the only the fields that is needed but the heavy response from server takes a time to get response.

Comment: the server response is not the Android (or any client) concern . In that case , try to read carefully the plugin's documentation .

Comment: but the time to get response is androids concern. if u need to get heavy data u'll need more time